# Setting user group specific permissions in InfoPath form

Tags: development, infopath

I am trying to set specific permissions to an infopath form if a certain check box is checked. Currently, the form will automatically inherit permissions from the top level site. I want to stop this and assign different permissions to that specific form when the check box is checked. Here is the code I have so far:

```
        string chkBox = GetNodeValue("/my:myTipLead/my:OBDM/my:DocumentDesignation/my:AllCISOL1And2Members");
        if (chkBox == "AllCISOL1And2Members")
        {

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use a workflow to set permissions? It is much simpler than managing that within the code behind of a form.

Comment: Can the workflow detect whether or not the checkbox has been checked? Sometimes this form will be viewed by everyone, other times, when the checkbox is checked, the form can only be viewed by a select few.

Comment: Absolutely, just promote that property to a column from within the form options and then you can reuse it for workflows.

Comment: Thank you so much Lori. When I get into work tomorrow morning I will try this out and if it works, select your answer as the correct answer.

Comment: I'm very new to SharePoint. From withing the Sharepoint Designer I have created a custom workflow with the permission settings I want but I am having trouble associating the checkbox property to a column. Do you know how or are there any tutorials out there that could help me out?

Comment: When you go to the Form Options within InfoPath Designer, click on Property Promotion and click Add, find the check box and promote it out to a column name.

Comment: I have done that and I can see the column in the document library with its correct value but I don't know how to assign custom permissions to each document that has that value in that column. Do you know how to do this?

Comment: Create a workflow that has a condition to check to see if that column is checked, if it is, then have it set permissions on the item. SPD should be able to do this for you. You can have it set to act either on creation of a new item or on edit of an existing item depending on which is needed.

Answer (score 1):

Check this blog post for [sample code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/robgruen/how-to-programmatically-set-permissions-on-filesfolders-in-a-sharepoint-document-library), or [this one](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/pranab/how-to-set-item-level-permission-for-sharepoint-2007-mosswss-listdocument-library-programmatically). You just need adapt one of these and use this code in your code block.